A-Weighted Noise Power Calculation
Can anyone please show me how to calculate the A-weighted noise power of a noise source.
Consider the case of a resistor having a spectral density of 4kTR.
What is the A-weighted noise power of this resistor?

Can you define what does A weighting mean in your context?

Audibility weighting curve perhaps? Regardless, it's just 4kT times the weighting spectral curve. Note that the noise power spectral density of a resistor does not depend on R, just 4kT

@Justme I mean the A-Weighting curve commonly applied in audio measurement.

A weighting accounts for the frequency dependence of the human ear. There are numerous useful links on google, including wikipedia which has a transfer function suitable for incorporation into software.
That's all you need, except the scaling factor that accounts for the system between the resistor and the sound-creating device.

Thanks for your answer. Is it correct to say the A-Weighted noise spectrum of the resistor is "4kTR x (A-Weighting Curve) x (A-Weighting Curve)"?   Here I multiply the noise spectrum of the resistor by the transfer function squared (i.e. A-weighting curve squared) to obtain A-weighted noise spectrum for this resistor, which can then be integrated from 20~20k to get the A-weighted noise power in the 20~20k bandwidth.
